# Trying to test Swift iOS app with ArcGIS

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, arcgis

I'm using ArcGIS pod in my project and everything is working fine. But now I'm trying to implement unit tests in my app and I got the error while run Product -> Test:

```
ld: framework not found ArcGIS for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My test file looks like:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest
@testable import MyApp
```

ArcGIS framework is a precompiled library.

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS', '~> 10.2.5'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
  pod 'ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS', '~> 10.2.5'

end
```

Why I can't test my app?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?

Comment: I've found on cocoapods that I can run `pod try ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I figured out my problem, I didn't have ArcGIS in the test target :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

```
Framework Search Path: $(SRCROOT)/Pods, recursive
```

in test build settings.